# cannot display texture in SDL 2

Tags: c++, sdl-2

I'm trying to display a texture onto the screen but all I'm getting is a black window.
No SDL Errors are being reported. There's a good chance that I'm missing something stupid, but I can't see it. Hopefully another set of eyes will help. Feel free to ask for more code/info.

**main.cpp**

```
SDL_Window * window;
SDL_Renderer * renderer;
SDL_Texture * grass;
SDL_Rect g_dst;
SDL_Event event;

Game app;
SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING);
window = SDL_CreateWindow("tmp", 100, 100, 640, 480, SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN);
renderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(window, -1, SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED);

g_dst.x = g_dst.y = 0;
g_dst.w = 640;
g_dst.h = 480;

grass = IMG_LoadTexture(renderer, "grass.bmp");

while (app.isRunning()) {
 app.pollEvents(&event);
 app.render_init();
 app.render(grass, NULL, &g_dst);
 app.render_end();
}
//SDL_Quit() is handled by the Game class' destructor
```

**Game.cpp**

```
//Only functions used for rendering are shown

void render_init(Uint8 red=0, Uint8 green=0, Uint8 blue=0, Uint8 alpha=255)
{
 SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, red, green, blue, alpha);
 SDL_RenderClear(renderer);
}

void render(SDL_Texture * texture, SDL_Rect * src, SDL_Rect * dest) {
    SDL_RenderCopy(renderer, texture, src, dest); 
}

void render_end() { SDL_RenderPresent(renderer); }
```

Comment: Are you certain it loads `grass` properly? You should always check for `NULL`

Comment: Ya I checked. Thats not the problem.

Comment: What if you only draw the `SDL_Rect` usnig `SDL_RendererDrawRect`?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you're initializing everything? please don't do that frequently, mind you that you're also initializing MANY unnecessary stuffs like for game controllers, etc. if the app gets bigger then the efficiency and the possibility of this app running at a smoot speed is at stake. 
I also noticed that you are declaring variables in the .cpp file, do that in the header file and just recall the header to the cpp file that will be using it.

You want to render the grass right? and render it as much as the screens size.

(I'll just assume that you used this in the game.cpp part, which is the very first file, thus, not regarding any classes made)

```
int winWidth = 680; //The reason for this is just in case you make the window resizable
int winHeight = 480; //then the texture would also resize along with the window


SDL_Window *window = window = SDL_CreateWindow("The Space Project", 100, 100, winWidth, winHeight, SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN);


SDL_Renderer *renderer = NULL; //I've set this to NULL so that we can know if 
the reason as to why your image is not rendering is because the renderer is not properly working.
renderer = SDL_CreateRenderer( window, -1, SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED);
if(renderer == NULL)
{
cout >> "Renderer is not working" >> endl; 
//This shows a line at the command prompt that your renderer doesn't have any output, thus, only having a NULL as an equivalent
}


SDL_Texture* grass= NULL;
grass= IMG_LoadTexture(renderer, "grass.bmp"); //As you can see, I've set the grass to Null again
if(grass == NULL)
{
cout >> "Grass have failed to initialize" >> endl;
/*I don't normally do this but it's very important if you really need trouble shooting guides
but this time, were here to check IF the grass.bmp entered the SDL_Texture grass, so if the system can't find the .bmp file then it would show this error
since the grass (SDL_Texture) still doesn't have anything inside it (NULL)*/
}


SDL_Rect grass_rect;
grass_rect.x = 0;
grass_rect.y = 0;
grass_rect.w = winWidth;
grass_rect.h = winHeight;


//Loop part, I'll skip some of it
while (!quit && mainEvent->type != SDL_QUIT) //!quit is just an imaginary Boolean I've typed)
{
    SDL_PollEvent(mainEvent); //Let's say you created the event already
    SDL_RenderClear(renderer);
    SDL_RenderCopy(renderer, grass, NULL, &grass_rect);
    //The NULL part is also similar to a rect but it's a limiting type, we didn't assign anything to it
since I assumed that you wanted the whole image to be rendered
    SDL_RenderPresent(renderer);
}
```

I revised the code and made it more efficient since your code called for useless extras which might result in lower performance.
I also notice that you tried calling for color changes?
use this

```
SDL_SetTextureColorMod(texture, red-value, green-value, blue-value);
```

and put it in the loops part under the render present of the same texture.

```
SDL_SetTextureColorMod(grass, 250, 250, 250);
```

Doing this would set all color values to 250, thus, having a white color, this change your texture color to white.

You're also wasting space on making the app.is running(), you could easily replace it with a boolean, which consumes much less space or you could omit it if you don't have an exit button inside the application and just make your loop read the SDL_QUIT, this saves space for the file, mind the efficiency.

If this still doesn't work then try replacing the image your using, make a simple one on paint name it something like "grass.png" or anything then try it again.

Don't forget to put the file in the proper folder, in the DEBUG folder if you haven't specified a folder, and also put it in the app folder so it would also read it when it executes as an .exe file and not as part of the debug command.